# Insert with Select in sql

Tags: sql

I use the following code to enter and select the content, but how do I fill in the fields at the same time?

```
insert into Labdowntest1 (TestID
                          , TestName
                          , Unit
                          , NormalValues
                          , Price
                          , labtestname
                          , IDtest) 
select * 
from testaddlab 
where IDtest='2'
```

Comment: What do YOU mean by "fill in the fields?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can put any expressions in the `select` including constants:

```
insert into Labdowntest1 ( TestID, TestName, Unit, NormalValues, Price, labtestname, IDtest)
    select TestID, 'My test', 'milliparsecs', 42, Price, labtestname, IDtest
    from testaddlab
    where IDtest = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `select * ...` will return 7 columns in the order defined with:

```
(TestID, TestName, Unit, NormalValues, Price, labtestname, IDtest)
```

If yes, then your code should work fine.
If no, you must explicitly select the column names of the table `testaddlab` that you want to insert in `Labdowntest1`:

```
insert into Labdowntest1 (TestID
                          , TestName
                          , Unit
                          , NormalValues
                          , Price
                          , labtestname
                          , IDtest) 
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
from testaddlab 
where IDtest='2'
```

So `col1`'s value will be inserted in the column `TestID`, `col2`'s value in the column `TestName` and so on.